# How to change BITS host url

Tags: microsoft-bits, codefluent

In my WPF project, I use CodeFluent to generate my BOM and my WCF Service application.
My WCF Service application is hosted on a separate server.

ServiceBinaryLargeObject data send by my WCF application contain a "ServerUrl" property.
Its default value starts with [http://localhost:1027/xxxxxxxxx].

How can i change this default BITS host url?

Thanks to anyone that can help me on that ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As explain in the CodeFluent Entities documentation (http://www.softfluent.com/documentation/BOM_BLOB_BITS_Url.html) you have to set the `bitServerUrl` attribute in the configuration file.

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="Sample" type="CodeFluent.Runtime.CodeFluentConfigurationSectionHandler, CodeFluent.Runtime"/>
  </configSections>

  <Sample connectionString="server=(local);database=Sample;Integrated Security=true"
          bitsServerUrl="http://localhost:1028/Sample/" />
</configuration>
```